# SMPS PCB Design Critic 2

Tags: power-supply, pcb, pcb-design, layout, switch-mode-power-supply

Thanks for your patient help, I am learning a lot. This is my (final, I hope) re-designed layout. What do you think?

10-32V to 5V 1.2A SMPS Buck Regulator Design.
The IC is [IFX91041](http://goo.gl/vzI8I) from infineon.

Here are the schematics and layouts:
http://www.mediafire.com/?69e66eje7vda1

(I was given 45 cm² (~6.98 inch²) area for both 5v 1.2A and 35V 4A.)

[image: Schematic]
[image: PCB Layout]

I did a "print screen" instead of bitmap output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much better than before.  Perhaps a little overkill on the vias, particularly the vias on the pads for U1 and D2.  My main concern is that the vias undeer U1 could suck all the solder away from the pad-- making the GND connection a little unreliable.  But if the vias are filled in then that shouldn't be an issue.  But in general, it is better to have too many vias than too little.

My only other criticism is the location of C3, and that trace that snakes under L2.  L2 is going to put a lot of noise on that trace, which could mess things up.  C3 should be placed between U1 and D2, and the traces should be really short-- or at least not routed under L2.